# CompizConfig color filter not processing shader files

Tags: compiz, color-management, redshift, glsl

I can enable the color filter, toggle screen filtering with *super-d*, and then switch filters with *ctrl-super-s*, but **only builtin filters work**.

[image]

I tried adding these filters (fragment shaders)

- https://www.geeks3d.com/20091009/shader-library-night-vision-post-processing-filter-glsl/
- https://github.com/twostraws/ShaderKit

Compiz doesn't complain when I select the .fsh file, or when switching to that filter. It just doesn't apply the expected filters.

Are the files I'm using possibly incompatible with Compiz? Does compiz support all GLSL, or just certain features?

I've got compiz version 0.9.14.0 with Ubuntu 19.04 running unity desktop.

I'm basically trying to get a redshift effect at the touch of a key.

Comment: I don't know about compiz or shaders but if you just want to change the screen temperature, and you're using x11, not Wayland, try `sct 3000` (or some other value). `sct` is a tiny program in the Ubuntu repos. Just `sct` will revert to the default temperature, 6500.

Comment: @DKBose changing temperature is a better way to do this and works across compositors. Thanks!